# Converting date to a format MYSQL understands?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have an variable which holds a date in UK format, ie 250711 which means the 25th July 2011

When I insert that into MYSQL it becomes 2025-07-11

How can I convert it before writing into MySQL such that is displayed correctly in MySQL as 2011-07-25?

Thanks alot,

Greg

Comment: I don't think "250711" is a date in any standard format ;)

Comment: but that's what I have to start with, it's come from the output of a solar panel invertor so I cannot change the source....

Comment: @VolkerK got your solution, but If you need to process the date in PHP somewhere else in the code, you can use this `strptime("250711", "%d%m%y")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use the string for an insert/update/select statement anyway you can let MySQL do the work

```
INSERT INTO ... STR_TO_DATE('250711','%d%m%y')
```

see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Answer (score 0):

Hey i hope it ain't toooo late to answer this; however it should help people who will view this question in the future

Just use this function:

```
function mysqlDate($input) {
  $output = false;
  $d = preg_split('#[-/:. ]#', $input);
  if (is_array($d) && count($d) == 3) {
    if (checkdate($d[1], $d[0], $d[2])) {
      $output = "$d[2]-$d[1]-$d[0]";
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Lets say that you have a date input as **$_POST['date']**, the function usage is going to be as in below:

```
$newDate = mysqlDate($_POST['date']);
```

Just store the **$newDate** in your database. Works like magic.